# Can I JOIN two tables with only one match for each row of one table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got one table, Classes, and another table that I call "courses" - that is, instances of a class taught by a specific person in a specific place. I want to pull a table that basically just shows me which Classes are active based on certain course parameters. For example:

```
CLASSES
class_id|class_name
--------|------------
       1|Class One
       2|Class Two
       3|Different Class
etc...

COURSES
course_id|class_id|room
---------|--------|--------
        1|       3|       1
        2|       3|       2
        3|       1|       1
        4|       3|       1
        5|       3|       2
        6|       2|       1
etc...
```

I'm wondering if there's a way that I can just get something like `SELECT classes.* FROM classes JOIN courses ON classes.class_id=courses.class_id WHERE courses.room=1` to return only one instance of each class. What's happening is that I'm getting only the classes that take place in room 1, but I'm getting multiple instances of each because there are multiple instances of that class in the course table in room 1.

I've tried all different sorts of `JOIN` - left, right, inner, etc. - and because I'm pulling from one table based on specifications from the other, they all appear to give me the same result.

So I'm getting:

```
class_id|  class_name  |course_id|room
--------|--------------|---------|--------
       1|Class One     |        3|       1
       2|Class Two     |        6|       1
       3|Diferent Class|        1|       1
       3|Diferent Class|        4|       1
etc...
```

But I want to just get:

```
class_id|  class_name  |course_id|room
--------|--------------|---------|--------
       1|Class One     |        3|       1
       2|Class Two     |        6|       1
       3|Diferent Class|        1|       1
etc...
```

Can I have it only `JOIN` on the first match for each row in Classes? I'm kind of new with MySQL so I'm having a little trouble expressing what I want to do clearly; I apologize.

Also: I'm pulling all of this into PHP via `PDO` - maybe there's a specific way to accomplish this in `PDO`?

Comment: If you only want one record from the COURSES table, which of them do you want?  IE: Always the lowest courseid (& room?) value?

Comment: It honestly doesn't matter. You're right I should have stated that. I'm just going for the CLASSES data; the only reason I'm going for COURSE is to get only those Classes that have corresponding courses with the correct criteria.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT
   classes.class_id,
   classes.name,
   courses.room
FROM classes
   JOIN courses
      ON classes.class_id=courses.class_id
WHERE courses.room=1
GROUP BY classes.class_id,classes.name,courses.room
```

GROUP BY allows you to aggregate results on the fields specified, so (in this instance) it will take just the unique tuple of (classes.class_id,classes.name,courses.room)

for more details
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: Not SELECTing the courses columns doesn't mean the output won't be duplicated.

Comment: @OMG Ponies  but the "group by" will

Comment: i've added a GROUP BY constraint, the query on the question doesn't select any data about courses

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I wanted to. Any reason not to use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: then comment comment of Ben Saufley on his own question makes it clear

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  cl.class_id, cl.class_name, c.course_id, c.room
FROM    classes cl
JOIN    courses c
ON      c.course_id = 
        (
        SELECT  ci.course_id
        FROM    courses ci
        WHERE   ci.class_id = cl.class_id
                AND ci.room = 1
        ORDER BY
                ci.class_id, ci.course_id -- or whatever
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

By changing the `ORDER BY` clause in the subquery, you can define which of the classes will be returned (that with the least or greatest `id` etc)

Comment: This seems to work, but it took phpMyAdmin 76 seconds to execute. Any idea what might be causing that?